# Within- and between-person variance in an unconditional means model

Tags: mixed-model

Testing an unconditional means model following the procedure in Chapter 4 of Willett and Singer *Applied Longitudinal Data Analysis* using the nlme package in R. The model takes the form

```
modelA <- lme(outcome ~ 1, df, random= ~1|id)
```

Below is the output:

```
Linear mixed-effects model fit by REML
 Data: alc1 
       AIC      BIC    logLik
  679.0049 689.5087 -336.5025

Random effects:
 Formula: ~1 | id
        (Intercept)  Residual
StdDev:   0.7570578 0.7494974

Fixed effects: alcuse ~ 1 
                Value  Std.Error  DF  t-value p-value
(Intercept) 0.9219549 0.09629638 164 9.574139       0

Standardized Within-Group Residuals:
       Min         Q1        Med         Q3        Max 
-1.8892070 -0.3079143 -0.3029178  0.6110925  2.8562135 

Number of Observations: 246
Number of Groups: 82
```

In the book it says the estimated within-person variance $\varepsilon_{0i}$ is 0.562 and the estimated between-person variance $\zeta_{0i}$ is 0.564 but I can't see this anywhere on this output. Does anyone know how they are getting these figures?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you run this code with lmer you immediately see variances next to intercept and residual. These are the values they refer to.

Here you can take the squares of stdev values under intercept and residual under random effects. These will be the values you are searching for.